# Automated Trading with TradingView (capital.com)

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

Today I coded a little bit with Pine Script in TradingView.

I have a strategy which worked well(backtesting), so I wanted to try it with real money.
I connected a broker(capital.com) to TradingView, but it won't open any trades with real money.

I can see the strategy making trades on the chart tho.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There is no automated order execution in Tradingview, you can only backtest a pinescript strategy.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same goal. Thanks.